# How to use sed to remove part of file path

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have lines like these

```
my_list=cloning/cloning-1.7.jar,commons/commons-lang-2.5.jar
my_lib_list=antlr/antlr-1.0.jar,aopa/aopa-1.0.jar
```

and I need to remove the part before '/' like this:

```
my_list=cloning-1.7.jar,commons-lang-2.5.jar
my_lib_list=antlr-1.0.jar,aopa-1.0.jar
```

I tried this

```
 sed -i -e "s/(?<=\/).*?(\.jar)//g"
```

Nothing happens. Regex seems to be right (might need to be inverted), but atleast something should change in the file, right?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]+\///g'` (or `sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+\///g'`)

Comment: `sed -E -i 's/[[:alnum:]]+\///g'` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern - `(?<=\/).*?(\.jar)` - contains a lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) and lazy matching quantifier (`*?`). Neither are supported by sed.

You can use

```
sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]+\///g'
```

See [the IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/0RTExr)

Pattern details:

- `[[:alnum:]]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric symbols
- `\/` - a literal `/`

Comment: By accepting, you also earned 2 points and can now upvote *helpful* questions and answers. See [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed -r 's#^([^=]+=)[^/]+/([^,]+,)[^/]+/(.*)#\1\2\3#'
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -r 's#^([^=]+=)[^/]+/([^,]+,)[^/]+/(.*)#\1\2\3#' <<<'my_list=cloning/cloning-1.7.jar,commons/commons-lang-2.5.jar'
my_list=cloning-1.7.jar,commons-lang-2.5.jar

$ sed -r 's#^([^=]+=)[^/]+/([^,]+,)[^/]+/(.*)#\1\2\3#' <<<'my_lib_list=antlr/antlr-1.0.jar,aopa/aopa-1.0.jar'           
my_lib_list=antlr-1.0.jar,aopa-1.0.jar
```